# Git sub-repository with URL relative to its parent repository

Tags: git, url, git-submodules, remote-repository

Currently, I have a normal repository A in GitHub, and I want to incorporate that repository A as a sub-repo of another repository B, then, remove original repository A and keep its copy within B. When I attempt this with Git submodules, the sub-repo becomes unusable.

After a lot of searching, I'm giving up with submodules, since I realize they are merely links pointing to some commit in an external repository.

Does exists a way to emulate submodules behaviour without loosing the sub-repo history when removing the original repository A? the best approach I've found so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it doesn't convince me since it mixes both super and sub-repo histories.

Comment: Just fetch the A history into B? Whether or not you use the result as a submodule or splice it in more tightly is a separate question, the submodule command doesn't have helpers for incorporated submodules but that's all it is, a helpers relieving you of mildly tedious tasks you could already do with Git anyway.